# Which dictionaries reveal the commonly mistaken usage of a word (i.e. how NOT to use a word)?

Tags: dictionary, resources

I encountered a very useful dictionary eight years ago, but have never been able to find a copy of it because I don't know what it's called. It not only gave examples in context of how to use the words, but also gave examples of how **NOT** to use the word (marked with an 【误】, if I remember correctly). Can anyone identify a dictionary that has this feature?

Comment: I find a dict called `现代汉语正误辞典`. Maybe it is the one you used before. Search it on Google, there still some online stores sell it.

Comment: Wouldn't how to not use the word be dependent on the user's first language. I'm quite sure Swedish and Japanese students make different mistakes.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I would imagine the utility of this dictionary varying depending on the learner's first language.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this《小學生的國語辭典》approved by the Taiwanese Ministry of Education for their primary school students. It contains the following features:

- 语文帮手 (or language assistant) to highlight certain words that require
  particular attention. For example:

  > 「人才」有才能和德性的人。例: ...
  >   請注意：指才能和知質義時「人才」也可以寫成「人材」：但是有木料或原料的意思時「木材」和「藥材」不可以寫作「木才」、「藥才」。
- 小提醒 (or small reminders) for listing synonyms (相似詞), antonyms (相反詞)
  and active terms (活用詞). For example:

  > 「井井有倏」形容倏理分明。例：他井井有倏，很受上司的器重。
  >  相似詞：井然有序。相反詞：亂七八糟。
- 追本溯源 (or trace the origin) to explain the historical background that
  give rise to the word. For example:

  > 「上當」的本義是指把物品典當給當鋪。據說從前有一个讀書人以經營當鋪為生，店裡的股東欺負他老實,紛紛把不值錢的物品拿來典當高價，沒多久，當鋪就關門大吉了。於是人們就把欺騙別人的行為,叫做「上當」。

Note that the dictionary is written in traditional Chinese (繁体字) and that it is availabe on Google Books.

Comment: Looks interesting, going to see if I can lay my hands on this one locally. You don't happen to know any other, similar books?

Comment: @OlleLinge, I happen to chance upon this while looking for references to answer another [question](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/1919/878). Hmm, there should be more out there. I think a good place to look for these gems would be at a national or university library, reference section. Internet is not really the place to search for these.